# Comparising Call and Put values with percentages

Tags: python-3.x

I want to comparise the different Call and Put values regarding time steps and simulations with a percentage change in value. First over different time steps with same simulations and then different simulations within same time steps.

The data is already in a pandas Dataframe

```
Time Steps  Simulations Call float. Put float.
0   12  100 19.369352   8.721473
3   12  1000    18.712544   8.705033
6   12  10000   18.054534   9.184100
1   52  100 18.278245   11.215671
4   52  1000    19.768560   10.478322
7   52  10000   19.147415   10.843398
2   252 100 20.088716   12.182678
5   252 1000    20.321271   11.477928
8   252 10000   19.781775   11.910613
```